# JS form validation works with chrome and firefox but not safari

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using this function to validate a form.  It is triggered 'onsubmit' when form is submitted.  isPresentCond2 determines if 'condition 2' is present (some forms on the site do not have a condition 2 input).  If the input is found to be null or an empty string it alerts the user and triggers a button.  It is working on all browsers except safari.

In Safari it will return x as false and trigger a confirm "please enter x"

No error messages.

```
function validateForm() {
    var isPresentCond2 = document.forms["form1"]["condition2"],
        x = document.forms["form1"]["condition1"].value,
        y,
        z = document.forms["form1"]["condition3"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
    confirm("Please enter a condition1 value");
    $("#Button1").trigger("click");
    return false;
    }
    if (isPresentCond2) {
        y = document.forms["form1"]["condition2"].value;
        if (y == null || y == "") {
            confirm("Please enter a condition2 value");
            $("#Button2").trigger("click");
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (z == null || z == "") {
    confirm("Please enter a condition3 value");
    $("#button3").trigger("click");
    return true;
    }
}
```

Sample Form:

```
<form name="form1" action="results.php" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" method="post>
<input type="radio" name="condition1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="condition1" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="condition1" value="3">

<input type="radio" name="condition2" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="condition2" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="condition2" value="3">

<input type="radio" name="condition3" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="condition3" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="condition3" value="3">

<button type="submit" class="btn-xl btn-success btn-block">See Results <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></button>
```

Should the if statements look more like this?

```
if (!X) ....
```

Is there an obvious reason that this function that would be causing problems with Safari?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample form please? Does Safari give you any error?

Comment: I just added a basic mockup of the form, i am not getting any errors.  In safari I am basically just getting a false positive.

Comment: Unselected radio groups will return empty which interpreted as `false`, so you should be able to use `if(!x)`, `if(!y)` ,`if(!z)` ... (check if it has the same behavior in IE to be safe though). You have `method="post>` which is missing a `"` at the end (in case it wasn't just a typo when posting in SO), such small typos might sometimes cause weird problems in different browsers. And it's a good practice to end self-closing elements with ` />`.